# how to make a relation between 2 tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSEFQ.png)

[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt1Pn.png)

[img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UGtI.png)

I got 3 tables as the pictures,

```
site_notifications

site_users

site__users__notifactions
```

I want to make a relationship so I show the notification details of a certain user

I tried

```
public function notification()
{
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\SiteNotification', 'App\Site_Users_Notifaction', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

but it gives me null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not like that. You should use [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Your table name should be:

1. users
2. notifactions
3. notifaction_user

Your model name should be:

1. User
2. Notifaction

Then in `User` class:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function notifactions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Notifaction::class);
    }
}
```

Then in `Notifaction` class:

```
class Notifaction extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then you could query like this:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->notifactions as $notifaction) {
    //
}
```

Comment: i changed the database tables and added it to my model and thats what i got now
http://prntscr.com/kv18o7

http://prntscr.com/kv18r3

http://prntscr.com/kv18uz

http://prntscr.com/kv190p

http://prntscr.com/kv194i

Comment: If you are not using the default naming convention, yo must specify the name of the pivot table and the fks: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');`. You can find this info in the link posted above.